# Question about moving unecrypted mongoDB to encrypted mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, encryption

so i am new in mongoD, i had a question about mongoDB

so i want to know about do mongoDB need to be migrate if i use mongoDb encryption in my unencrypted mongoDB ?

so for example i had unecrypted mongoDB and then my company buying  enterprise mongoDB and use the encrpytion do i need migrate my database to the encrpyted database ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you need to migrate your existing data.

It depends, what you mean by "encrypted MongoDB".

[Encryption at Rest](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/)? If you have a ReplicaSet, then it is rather simple. Just configure Encryption at Rest on a SECONDARY member and restart it. `mongod` performs an initial sync and encrypts the data during the sync up process. Repeat the step on all SECONDARIES and finally on your PRIMARY member.

If you run a stand-alone MongoDB, then you have to export your data, then configure Encryption at Rest and then import your data again, i.e. you will have a service interruption.

[Client-Side Field Level Encryption](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/csfle/) and [Queryable Encryption](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/queryable-encryption/) would be more difficult. They will also require changes on your application side.